# MongoDB агрегация вложенных массивов, выбор дефолтного значения

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Есть коллекция вида:

```
{ price: 10.2, name: [
   {code: "ru-RU", text: "Russian Name"},
   {code: "en-US", text: "En Name"}
   ...
]
```

...

После агрегации мне нужно получить коллекцию вида

```
{ price: 10.2, name: {code: "ru-RU", text: "Russian Name"},
...
```

то есть условие такое: мне нужно с массива оставить только русский язык, если русского языка нет то должен быть за дефолтом только английский, а если английского нет то должен быть null. Как это можно сделать?